# Write regular expression to find all tags with specific attribute

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2013

For example:

```
<abc:TextLinkButton ID="someID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    CssClass="someClass" Text="Some text" meta:resourcekey="SomeResource" />
```

I need to find all " **abc:TextLinkButton** " tags, that have **ClientIDMode** attribute.
I want search all tags in VisualStudio 2013.
Thanks for help.

---

Edit:
One more think.
Is there quick way how to remove ClientIDMode="Static" attribute, from all abc:TextLinkButton tags, in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: What language are you using? I'm not sure a regex is the best solution for this job.

Comment: Where are you running this regex?  I assume Visual Studio search, if so, which version (as the regex format for VS2010 and under is different from VS2012 and above)?

Comment: Seriously, do yourself a favor - do not parse xml with regexes. Your problem can be trivially solved by xpath.

Comment: @georg - no it can't be "trivially solved by xpath" if the OP is wanting to find all instances of the ASP.NET control in his project/solution, as I guess he is.  I'm aware HTML and Regex do not mix as standard (I have commented as such many times) but I think this is a slightly different situation... although you're right, it's not a good situation

Comment: @freefaller: so, the question is about using the "find" function in their IDE? They should have stated that.

Comment: @georg - I don't know that... but as ClientIDMode isn't rendered to the browser, it is my **asumption**.  I did ask the OP to state where they were running it, but as with so many OP's they ask and then never respond to clarification questions. Sigh

Comment: I want search all tags in VisualStudio 2013

Comment: @merso0027 - it would have saved a lot of trouble if you'd stated that as part of your question, rather than people guessing/making assumptions!

Comment: @freefaller- Sorry for that. Thanks for advice. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `<abc:TextLinkButton[^>]+ClientIDMode\b`

Comment: Is there quick way how to remove ClientIDMode="Static" attributes, from all abc:TextLinkButton tags in visual Studio 2013?

Comment: @merso0027 I don't use Visual Studio, but try to replace `(<abc:TextLinkButton[^>]+)ClientIDMode="Static"` by `$1`.

Comment: WoooooW! I must learn regular expresions:). Thank you very much :)